# Indoor GPS 3D for navigation

Tags: mobile-robot, navigation

I'm looking Indoor GPS system for agriculture tasks in a greenhouse.
I want to make an autonomous robot who can navigate by "GPS", I want the system to be 3D (x,y,z) and allowing the I can use robotic arm. I thought using **Marvelmind** precise +/- 2cm Indoor GPS system but I'm not sure it's accurate enough. Has anyone experience with it.

What is best technology/system for that purpose?

Is anyone familier with RTK methods and can tell me if it can works inside greenhouses?

Comment: You will likely not be able to use GPS for precise navigation in a greenhouse due to multipath and other factors. You should either investigate other methods or investigate indoor GPS.

Answer (score 1):

Indoor operation  **rules  out**  the  use  of  GPS  due to signal attenuation and considerable inconsistency incorporated with localization drift. In such scenarios, simultaneous localization and mapping (SLAM) provides an appealing alternative to estimate the current state of robot and construct the map.

For indoor environments, depending on the accuracy needed, two popular methods are considered:

- **Visual SLAM**:

Process of estimating the ego-motion of an agent (e.g., vehicle, human, and robot) equipped with a single or multiple cameras. Typical vision sensors are monocular, stereo and RGB-D cameras.

- **Visual-Inertial SLAM**:

Dynamic motion, a lack of visible texture, and the need for precise structure and motion estimates reduce visual SLAM capabilities to construct accurate map and estimate the pose of the camera. The measurement from an inertial measurement unit (IMU) would be a good supplement for visual measurements to improve the result.

Please note that if revising the place is not required in your application (problem known as *loop closure*), the SLAM automatically reduces to odometry.

Answer (score 0):

BLE Bluetooth Low Energy beacons can be used for internal location, you will need a few distributed throughout your space.

https://www.banggood.com/JDY-08-4_0-Bluetooth-Module-BLE-CC2541-Airsync-For-IBeacon-Compatible-With-Arduino-p-1325934.html?rmmds=search